# Possible causes for pointer value change in C?

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I've got a function

```
void* fn( void* ptr ){...}
```

that I am using as the starting method in a pthread. Somewhere in the function, I get an error where `ptr` (usually pointing to a struct) changes from its original value to 0x100000000000000 ( from `printf("%p")` ), although nowhere in the function `fn` is it being assigned to, I am only reading its values like `ptr->value`. Any ideas?

Comment: Without code, we can't tell. But are sure you haven't accidentally used `=` instead of `==` somewhere?

Comment: @DarkDust not only do I not compare ptr with anything, I don't compare any of its subvalues with anything, I only use them to assign to other values or pass to functions. The question is I don't assign to ptr, and I don't pass &ptr to anything, so how could ptr possibly change?

Comment: specifically show us what _ptr_ points to originally and how/where that is allocated. It could be that the _ptr_ goes out of scope during the course of program execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a buffer overflow in a called function.

Assuming a Linux system, I usually debug such bugs with GDB *hardware watchpoints*.

You could also run your program thru `valgrind`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: This was a good call -- hardware watchpoints didn't find anything, but by adding more local variables to the stack I can prevent the error from happening. Now I just have to find out what causes it.

Comment: put a break point inside your `fn` (near the beginning). When you reach in, do `p &ptr;` in GDB. Let's pretend it answers `0x123456`; do `watch *(void**)0x123456`.

Comment: I've been using watch, but it still somehow changes without notifying me.